# Parse-Server: APNS Notification caused error: 8 for device

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, parse-server

I run the current parse-server version:

```
├─┬ parse@1.6.14
└─┬ parse-server@2.1.6
  ├─┬ body-parser@1.15.0
  │ ├── parseurl@1.3.1
  │ ├── range-parser@1.0.3
  │ │ │ ├─┬ parse-json@2.2.0
  │ │ ├── jsonparse@1.2.0
  ├─┬ parse@1.7.1
```

I receive this error when I try to send out a push notification:

```
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: Can not find sender for push type android, {"where":{"deviceType":{"$in":["ios"]}},"data":{"title":"The Shining","badge":"1","alert":"All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy."}}
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: APNS Notification caused error: 8 for device  Device {
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: token: <Buffer 65 97 1a 22 d3 01 da 60 7a 10 5e 2f a8 95 e2 79 73 08 04 36 4c 94 08 1d de 8d df de fb 6e 6e 7b>,
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: connIndex: 0,
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: appIdentifier: 'com.stefantrauth.Xenim' } { encoding: 'utf8',
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: payload:
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: { title: 'The Shining',
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: aps:
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: { badge: undefined,
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: sound: undefined,
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: alert: 'All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.',
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: 'url-args': undefined,
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: category: undefined } },
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: expiry: undefined,
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: priority: 10,
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: retryLimit: -1,
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: device: undefined,
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: compiled: '{"title":"The Shining","aps":{"alert":"All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy."}}',
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: truncateAtWordEnd: false,
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: _alert: 'All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.' }
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: APNS Connection 1 Notification transmitted to 65971a22d301da607a105e2fa895e279730804364c94081dde8ddfdefb6e6e7b
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: APNS Connection 0 Disconnected
Mar 18 14:35:18 xsn-app parse-app[31790]: APNS Connection 0 Connected
```

However the push message gets delivered correctly to my device. I have only one single device registered to this parse-server.

This is how I send out my push message:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
  -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "where": {
          "deviceType": {
            "$in": [
              "ios"
            ]
          }
        },
        "data": {
          "title": "The Shining",
          "alert": "All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy."
        }
      }'\   https://myserver.com/parse/push
```

Can anyone tell me what `APNS Notification caused error: 8 for device` means?

My thoughts on this: This looks like parse is trying to send out the notification two times: First with the production.p12 certificate and after that with the development.p12 certificate. The first try fails, because the device token belongs to a device in development mode.

I run parse-server with `NODE_ENV=development`. So this might be an issue with parse server trying to send the notification to production?

Comment: I opened a ticket on Github: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1096